# Unity3d Download asset bundles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'll try to find best solution for downloading new bundles or replace old versions of bundles. Best way to do it(imho) - use LoadFromCacheOrDownload. But if user have bad 3g connection that function will resume download or start? If it will not resume download, may be someone know better solution for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LoadFromCacheOrDownload`. From my experience the implementation is decent. If the network drops it won't restart the download on it's own, you'll have to call `LoadFromCacheOrDownload` again. On the other hand it does signal you when something went wrong via the [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class and you can try again.

A few notes on the Unity Caching:

- if the download fails midway and you use [Caching.IsVersionedCached](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Caching.IsVersionCached.html) it will report as the asset is download, but it actually isn't
- You can't selectively clear the cache, so either clear the entire cache or nothing at all

Comment: Thanks for you reply!
But how redownload if IsVersionedCached says that asset was downloaded?

Comment: it will happen automatically when you try call LoadFromCacheOrDownload. I was just letting you know that if you use that API to show the user that a content is available it actually isn't, but Unity will download it for you